# Rename [yugioh-duel-links] → [yu-gi-oh-duel-links]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The proper name of the game is *[Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Duel_Links)*, with hyphens in the first word. We should rename the tag to match that.

- [yugioh-duel-links](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yugioh-duel-links) → [yu-gi-oh-duel-links](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-duel-links)

This will also match [Board & Card Games Stack Exchange's tag](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh) for the physical card game, and [yu-gi-oh-gx-beginning-of-destiny](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-gx-beginning-of-destiny) on this site.

Comment: Well, “yugioh” is rather a mash of letters.  I'd change it for that reason alone.

Comment: cant really say I'd like to type a - every two letters but it does make sense lol

Comment: @Zissouu If we keep the other spelling as a synonym, then you can still type in `yugioh` and it will be converted to the new tag automatically.

Comment: @Thunderforge oh I agree with the idea thats why I upvoted. I just seem to never be able to find the - when typing it was just me complaining.

Comment: @Zissouu actually, if you type "yugioh" without hyphens, the system will suggest [yu-gi-oh] tag. But I agree if not synonymized, users with "tag creation" privilege might accidentally create "yugioh" tag again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done:**

- [yugioh-duel-links](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yugioh-duel-links) → [yu-gi-oh-duel-links](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh-duel-links)